# pinging an unknown hosts from centos resolves

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, ping, networking, nslookup

I am seeing very strange behavior with servers running **CentOS 6.4 x64**.

If I run a ping on a host which clearly doesn't exist:

```
➜  ~  ping sdafsadfdsadfsasdfasdoi.com
PING sdafsadfdsadfsasdfasdoi.com.mydomain.com (X.X.X.X) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from web2.mydomain.com (X.X.X.X): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
```

Notice that is simply added mydomain.com to the end, and since I have a wildcard DNS entry *.mydomain.com it resolved. This is not the desired behavior. I expect this to return unknown host.

If I run `nslookup`:

```
➜  ~  nslookup sdafsadfdsadfsasdfasdoi.com
Server:     208.67.222.222
Address:    208.67.222.222#53

** server can't find sdafsadfdsadfsasdfasdoi.com: NXDOMAIN
```

Ok, so nslookup returns what I expect.

Any idea why this is happening, and how to prevent it, and return unknown host from a ping?

### UPDATE

**doing:**

```
search .
```

**In `/etc/resolv.conf` fixed the issue. This feel like a dirty hack though. Is there a more elegant and best practices solution?**

Comment: This is expected, it's using the DNS search suffix specified in your interface/resolv.conf which will match your wildcard entry.

Comment: How can I prevent this? I want it to fail.

Comment: Stop using wildcard DNS.

Comment: That's not an option, required for the application.

Comment: You can remove it if you like, it's there as a helper not required for basic functionality...but some apps/services will expect it to be there and you will need to use FQDNs for any references to local network resources.

Comment: doing `search .` in `/etc/resolv.conf` fixed the issue. This feel like a dirty hack though. Is there a more elegant and best practices solution?